# View history in Skype

Tags: apps, skype

Does anybody know how to view history in Skype? I have several rooms in my Skype, and when I open Skype, some history messages get downloaded but not all.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen, it's restricted to only show a couple of weeks worth of interactions, and it is not currently configurable to change the time period